# Crypto platform that provides a good looking report for the purpose of obtaining mortgage?

Tags: exchanges, taxes, accounting

My mortgage broker:

> They aren’t happy with your proof of deposit. The bitcoins are fine. But you will need to provide a statement of your portfolio. It needs to come from the provider / platform where your funds are held. It needs to have your name on it.

I don't think it is possible to convince them cryptographic signature is enough. They want to see a statement...

Tried looking at popular platforms...

#### Coinbase

[image]

#### Binance (some dust)

[image]

## I would like to make them happy...

...which platform offers a good looking statement?

Comment: I'm sorry about the votes to close. Real life use case, real life problem. Looking for a platform that has a feature called **"good looking reports"**. Just like someone looking for a wallet that supports **Lightning Network on Testnet**. I was thinking about hiring an artist / graphic designer to produce me a statement from **United Bank of Bitcoin** and I would persistent that it states the truth, rather than https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_fraud 